# How to set audio volume using React and Twilio?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, twilio

I am using Twilio for streaming audio and video, and I want to be able to control the audio volume using React instead of using the document.getElementById('audio') method. Currently, I have the following code which sets the audio volume based on a value from guide.liveDetails.volume:

```
 useEffect(() => {
        const audioTrack = audioTracks[0];
        const audio = document.getElementById('audio');
        audio.volume = (guide.liveDetails.volume / 100);
        if (audioTrack && mic) {
            audioTrack.attach(audioRef.current);
            return () => {
                audioTrack.detach();
            };
        }
    }, [audioTracks, mic, guide]);

  return (
        <>
            {camera && <video ref={videoRef} autoPlay={true} />}
            <audio id="audio" ref={audioRef} autoPlay={true} muted={!mic} />
        </>
    );
```

However, I want to know how to set the volume using React instead of using document.getElementById('audio'). Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: You can use useRef https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#useref

Comment: @SurjeetBhadauriya how to do it? I have already ref for it. I am using the Twilio audio for it.

Comment: Give it a try by creating an instance of audioRef as suggested in the link like: const audioRef = useRef(); and then use audioRef to access volume like audioRef.volume or maybe audioRef.current.volume

Comment: thanks! its work @SurjeetBhadauriya

Comment: Cheers it worked!! @רועי אנגל Can you please up vote my answer then?

Answer (score 3):

You can use `useRef` instead of document as shown below

```
const audioRef = useRef(); // on the top of your function component
```

and then use `audioRef` to access the element.

```
audioRef.current.volume // use this where you want
```

Comment: this also works for video :)